# Remove all occurrences of a given element from a list

Tags: python, list

I want to remove all occurrences of a given element from a list but the problem is the way I'm doing I'm removing only half of it.

```
lsChars = ['x', 'y', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']

for c in lsChars:
    if c == "a":
        lsChars.remove(c)

print(lsChars)
```

The output is:
['x', 'y', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']

But should be:
['x', 'y', 'b', 'c']

How can I fix that?

Comment: `for c in lsChars[:]:`

Comment: when you remove item from list then it moves elements and then `for` can skip some of them. Better use `lsChars.count(c)` to see how many times remove it. OR create new list only with elements which you want to keep.

Comment: `.remove()` has to traverse the whole list each time you call it. Creating a new one is more efficient, even if you assign it back to the variable: `lsChars = [c for c in lsChars if c != "a"]` (`lsChars[:] = …` to modify the actual list in place). Another efficient option is to loop backwards `for i in range(len(lsChars) - 1, -1, -1): if lsChars[i] == "a": del lsChars[i]`

Comment: Use `lsChars = ['x', 'y', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'c']

for c in reversed(lsChars):
    if c == "a":
        lsChars.remove(c)`

Comment: You can create a dictionary of the elements in the list (using 
`dict.fromkeys(lsChars)`) which will automatically remove the duplicate items. Then you can convert this dictionary back to list(Using `list()`).So you can write in one line like :  `mylist=list(dict.fromkeys(lsChars))`.

Comment: new = [ls for ls in lsChars if ls is not "a"]

Answer (score -1):

[ c for c in lsChars if c != 'a']

this works.

Comment: it gives the same wrong result. It has the same problem with moving elements when items are removed from list.

Comment: should run it before posting it